# Inheritance in java(subclass of a subclass)

Tags: java, inheritance, subclassing

say we have three classes: class a , class b , class c;
class b inherits class a , if we define that class c inherits class b(which inherits class a) will the code give an error .If not the can we say that class c inherits class a;

in all i ask that can there be a subclass of a subclass??

Comment: Of course you can. Why don't you simply try it? You just need 3 lines of code to test it.

Comment: You should check out "https://stackoverflow.com/help" for help on how and what to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, **yes**, you could definitely have a "chain" of inheritance. When you have a class A that inherits another class B, then it doesn't matter whether class B inherits from another class.

Though, you should keep in mind that a class is not able to inherit from multiple classes (it would throw a compiler error). Multiple inheritance in Java is achievable through the use of interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Multilevel inheritance refers to a mechanism where one can inherit from a derived class, thereby making this derived class the base class for the new class.

for example

```
Class A
{
   public void methodA()
   {
     System.out.println("Class A method");
   }
}
Class B extends A
{
public void methodB()
{
System.out.println("class B method");
}
}
Class C extends B
{
   public void methodC()
   {
     System.out.println("class C method");
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     C obj = new C();
     obj.methodA(); //calling grand parent class method
     obj.methodB(); //calling parent class method
     obj.methodC(); //calling local method
  }
}
```